# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl

Tags: classpath, jython, libraries, java

I am working on an application that executes a **Jython 2.5.3** script from **JAVA 1.6.027**. The script just open a file using codecs library and it looks like this:

```
try:
    from codecs import open as codecs_open
except ImportError:
    print 'ERROR', 'Could not import.'

CODECS_LIST = ['latin-1', 'utf-8', 'utf-16', '1250', '1252']

def open_file(filename, mode):
    '''
    DOC
    '''
    for encoding in CODECS_LIST:
        try:
            f = codecs_open(filename, mode, encoding)
            f.read()
            f.close()
            print 'INFO', "File %s supports encoding %s." % (filename.split("\\")[-1], encoding)
            ...
        except:
            ...
```

When I execute this script debugging in **Eclipse**, everything works OK, but when I execute the part of the JAVA application that invokes this script, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.getChannel(RandomAccessFile.java:253)
    at org.python.core.io.FileIO.fromRandomAccessFile(FileIO.java:173)
    at org.python.core.io.FileIO.<init>(FileIO.java:79)
    at org.python.core.io.FileIO.<init>(FileIO.java:57)
    at org.python.core.PyFile.<init>(PyFile.java:135)
    at org.python.core.PyTraceback.getLine(PyTraceback.java:65)
    at org.python.core.PyTraceback.tracebackInfo(PyTraceback.java:38)
    at org.python.core.PyTraceback.dumpStack(PyTraceback.java:109)
    at org.python.core.PyTraceback.dumpStack(PyTraceback.java:120)
    at org.python.core.Py.displayException(Py.java:1080)
    at org.python.core.PySystemState.excepthook(PySystemState.java:1242)
    at org.python.core.PySystemStateFunctions.__call__(PySystemState.java:1421)
    at org.python.core.Py.printException(Py.java:1053)
    at org.python.core.Py.printException(Py.java:1012)
    at org.python.util.jython.run(jython.java:264)
    at org.python.util.jython.main(jython.java:129)
```

The JAVA application is able to execute others similar jython scripts. I have detected that the **class sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl** is in the library rt.jar, which is inside */bin/common/* folder and included in my **classpath** via **jvm.cfg** file:

```
...    
#LIBRARY PATH
./bin/common;...
...
```

The same way I do it with other libraries that work fine.

I have been stacked with this problem for a few days, so any help will be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: You shouldn't include rt.jar in the class path, the classes in it should be loaded by the system class loader only.

Comment: yeah, in fact I included it this way just to test if it could be a solution. What I have in jvm.cfg is #LIBRARY PATH
./bin/common;...

Comment: Looks like a JRE mismatch to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem has been resolved by reinstalling *Java Runtime Environment*, in my case version **jre-6u45**

Comment: jvm bug do you think?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me because the `mysql` package that I had installed was installed globally and required root privileges, so when running java, I had to include `sudo` to get it to work correctly.