# selenium webdriver failed with: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl

Tags: java, selenium

I am working with selenium and while trying to run a simple test I get:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl

I have search stack's posts and found only this one: [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18444785/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-sun-nio-ch-filechanne)

But the answer there dodn't helped me. 
The webdriver is not been initialized and get:

Failed to invoke configuration method com.tf.qa.tempTests.tests.TempTestBase.setDriver:Could not initialize class sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl

Details:

Build info: version: '2.46.0', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_40'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did it work in any driver??

Comment: Did it work in latest driver ???

Comment: It works locally with any remote web driver version. but when trying to run on grid which located on external server (jenkins), I get this error. I am using a container for the remote web-driver:                                             public ThreadLocal<RemoteWebDriver> driverContainer = new ThreadLocal<>(); //driver container for driver thread save when working in parallel, don't know if it's related.

Comment: Did it work on remote machine when set by docker ???

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58214272/9691802, check this it worked with me after 4 days trying.

Answer (score 0):

So it was fixed after I restarted the hub server (did it straight from Jenkins) and lunched all nodes in grid again.